# How to convert a java generated public key to pem format with openssl

Tags: java, python, rsa, keytool

I've got a public RSA key which is as following:

```
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHn/hfvTLRXViBXTmBhNYEIJeGGGDkmrYBxCRelri
LEYEcrwWrzp0au9nEISpjMlXeEW4+T82bCM22+JUXZpIga5qdBrPkjU08Ktf5n7Nsd7n9ZeI0YoAKCu
b3ulVExcxGeS3RVxFai9ozERlavpoTOdUzEH6YWHP4reFfpMpLzwIDAQAB
```

I need to convert it into PEM format so that I can write my own python code using this public key, I see there're many answers to the opposite operation, but right now I need to convert it from JAVA style to PEM, can anyone help?

Comment: How did you generate the key? Java has a few ways it can represent them

Comment: What python package are you using that you think needs the key in certain format?

Comment: oliv's solution works, but thank you all the same:P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert back the base64 encoded pub key and throw it to openssl:

```
echo "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHn/hfvTLRXViBXTmBhNYEIJeGGGDkmrYBxCRelriLEYEcrwWrzp0au9nEISpjMlXeEW4+T82bCM22+JUXZpIga5qdBrPkjU08Ktf5n7Nsd7n9ZeI0YoAKCub3ulVExcxGeS3RVxFai9ozERlavpoTOdUzEH6YWHP4reFfpMpLzwIDAQAB" | base64 -d | openssl rsa -inform der -pubin -out rsakey.pub
```

`-inform der` is telling to openssl to take the key as binary (default is PEM)

`-pubin` tells to expect a public (default is private)

`-out` is to write the key

---

Another way is to append the openssl tags before and after the base64 encoded rsa public key:

```
sed 's/^/-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n/;s/$/\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----/' <<< "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDHn/hfvTLRXViBXTmBhNYEIJeGGGDkmrYBxCRelriLEYEcrwWrzp0au9nEISpjMlXeEW4+T82bCM22+JUXZpIga5qdBrPkjU08Ktf5n7Nsd7n9ZeI0YoAKCub3ulVExcxGeS3RVxFai9ozERlavpoTOdUzEH6YWHP4reFfpMpLzwIDAQAB" | openssl rsa -pubin
```

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop through all the certs in the current folder that have the .cer extension
for cert in *.cer
do

#get filename wihtout ext
filename="${cert%.*}"
#echo ${filename} 

#convert to PEM
openssl x509 -inform der -in ${cert} -outform pem -out ${filename}.crt

done
```

I used this to convert certificates to pem format.  Hopefully it can help

Comment: Hi Craig, thanks for your quick answer, however the key I posted is not a DER one, it's a JAVA generated one, with openssl x509 -inform der -in ${cert}, I just got following error:

Comment: unable to load certificate
140258637911704:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1197:
140258637911704:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:374:Type=X509

Comment: What is the extension on the file?

Comment: This: https://www.calazan.com/how-to-convert-a-java-keystore-jks-to-pem-format/ might be worth a read

Comment: In fact it's not in file, just a string as I posted in the question, oliv's solution works good, but thank you all the same.